# com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: admin_host

Tags: java, websphere, application-server

Can any one help me to fixe this issue.

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: admin_host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was facing the above issue becoz of i had changed vitual host from admin console , so when i was trying to start server it was throwing below error.

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: admin_host

solution : please create the new profile , you can follow the below wesite  steps

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_8.0.4/com.ibm.servertools.doc/topics/tcprofile70.html

Comment: While it is true that re-creating the profile would resolve the issue, that's because the entire configuration gets deleted and re-created with the default values. Your question does not have enough information to see the problem in detail, so the usefulness of this solution is very limited.